# Is there a Guix equivalent of nix-shell?

Tags: guix

As the manual page for `nix-shell` describes it:

> Nix can be used to provides some kind of virtual environment through the nix-shell command.

Much like Python developers commonly create a virtual environment of python packages that they then activate, `nix-shell` can be used to create a virtual environment of any packages available in the Nix package manager; a tool which allows the user to download and activate a virtual shell environment with the packages needed to develop some piece of software without polluting the user or system environment.

With the background out of the way, my question is then: Is there an equivalent of `nix-shell` available for the Guix package manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`guix shell`](https://guix.gnu.org/en/blog/2021/from-guix-environment-to-guix-shell/) now.

```
$ guix shell hello
```

brings you fresh environment with `hello` package installed inside it. It is "drop-in" replacement for `guix environment --ad-hoc`.

If you rather want *dependencies* of `hello` (for example, to start development of it) then all you need is as simple as:

```
$ guix shell -D hello
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `guix environment --ad-hoc`. For example:

```
guix environment --ad-hoc python python-pandas
```

That creates a temporary Guix profile with Python and Pandas installed, but could equally be any other packages in Guix. Specifically with Python you need to include `python` so that it is aware of `python-pandas`. The above gives you a temporary profile that still has access to exsting environment variables and packages in the current user and system profiles.

For a more isolated (and hence reproducible) environment, you can use `--pure` to hide existing environment variables, user profile and system profile:

```
guix environment --pure --ad-hoc [packages]
```

For full containerized isolation, which alows you to restrict filesystem and network access:

```
guix environment --container --ad-hoc [packages]
```

The last two options will require you to explicitly specify a whole lot of the more fundamental packages, such as `coreutils`; more effort, but more reproducible.

See [invoking guix environment](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/guix.html#Invoking-guix-environment) for more.

I also use a program called `direnv` which automatically activates/deactivates these profiles and other environment variables for various projects. You create a `.envrc` file for your project something like this:

```
use guix --ad-hoc python python-matplotlib python-html5lib python-mypy python-flake8
source ~/.virtualenvs/base-django-py38/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.dev
```

The `use guix` is a custom feature of direnv, which is only [briefly documented](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/master/stdlib.sh).